# What's the difference between the 2 model configs in api calls

Tags: angular

I have the following method calling an api in my service file:

```
getDetail(id: number): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get<any>("api/detail/" + id, { responseType: 'json', observe: 'response' })
    }
```

I'm being lazy and just using `any` for now as the model/interface.

My question is what's the difference between the 2 different `anys`? In what circumstances could they possibly be different from one another? I sometimes see other people leaving off the 2nd `any` from the second line, ie:

```
return this.http.get("api/detail/" + id, { responseType: 'json', observe: 'response' })
```

Comment: You have no type control in neither of those cases so it does not matter and dont waste your time on it.

Comment: @Antoniossss I know as I've already said I'm being lazy at the moment. I'm simply asking why is it declared twice?

Comment: For no reason, you can skip either of those.

Answer (score -1):

> My question is what's the difference between the 2 different anys?

none, it just says that `any` is of type `any` (duuuh, you don't say)

> In what circumstances could they possibly be different from one
> another?

when you want to make your life even harder and you want to cheat compiler into thinking that return type is of given type

```
class MyType{public hello(){console.log("hi!")}}

getDetail(id: number): Observable<MyType> {
        //turn off type controll
        return this.http.get<any>("api/detail/" + id, { responseType: 'json', observe: 'response' })
    }

getDetail(5).subscribe(ret=>ret.hello());; //good luck in doing that, but compiler wont complain
```